# Ошибка reCaptcha

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

В связи с последними событиями необходимо было поменять reCaptcha с первой версии на вторую (google уходит от поддержки v1). Сайт стоит на wordpress, формы используются CF7. Там есть уже готовая интеграция с reCaptcha. Зарегистрировал по новой сайт уже на версии каптчи 2, поменял ключи и коды в админке и теперь в консоле появляется ошибка "reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element".
Правильно ли я понимаю, что откуда то тянется первая каптча и вторая на нее накладывается или же здесь другое? При этом каптча работает и все нормально отправляется.

p.s. Вообще хотел установить invisible reCaptcha так как более удобная, но не удалось там вообще на сайте вылетает постоянный `alert` что нет интернет соединения, а потом вылетает каптча на которой написано "Неверный ключ".

Answer (score 0):

Invisible reCaptcha выдает такую ошибку, если ключа нет или он сгенерирован, но не того типа - например, v2. Вам в консоли reCaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin?hl=ru#list надо зарегистрировать ваш сайт ещё раз, выбрав тип "Invisible reCaptcha".